# PHP/Wordpress: include hours & minutes in ascending list

Tags: php, sql, datetime, wordpress

I'm modifying a Wordpress plugin that another dev wrote a couple years back. In the PHP code, he's created a `$now` variable to get the current time. Then further down, we're displaying a list of content filtered in ascending order. The problem I'm running into is that if there are multiple posts on the same day, it's not filtering them in ascending order according to the hours and minutes; only the day.

You can see what I'm talking about here: http://alhughesauction.com/upcoming-auctions
The first two auctions are on the same day, but the second one should actually display first since it's at 11am and the other is at 3pm.

This is how the `$now` is defined:

```
$now = "'" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("now-5hours")) . "'";
```

As per the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), I tried adding `-g` to `"Y-m-d"`, but that didn't work.

Here is where we're grabbing the data from the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . AH_DATA . " WHERE date >= {$now} ORDER BY date ASC" . $limit;
```

I would venture to guess that I simply need to get the `$now` variable to add hours and minutes, but I'm still learning the ropes of PHP :)

Comment: have you tried using date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Bhumi** said use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` for `$now`

```
$now = "'" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now-5hours")) . "'";
```

Also the datatype of `date` column should be `timestamp`, if it is not use this query for ordering in ascending order

```
$sql = "SELECT timestamp( `date` ) as 'date', * FROM " . AH_DATA . " 
WHERE `date` >= {$now} ORDER BY 1 ASC" . $limit;
```

`date` is reserved word in `mysql` use `` ` `` around column name to use it like column name

**Edit**

Try this query

```
$sql = "SELECT timestamp(CONCAT(`date`," ",`time` ) as 'date', * FROM " . AH_DATA . " 
WHERE `date` >= {$now} ORDER BY 1 ASC" . $limit;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yogesh. However, after trying ```date(Y-m-d H:i:s");``` and the new ```timestamp``` datatype, it still doesn't work....I can't tell you much more than it just doesn't work. Any more ideas?

Comment: @TrevanHetzel What is datatype of `date` column? And show what is the data coming from database.

Comment: Would this help? http://t.hetz.co/OngZ From what I can tell, the datatype is date...

Comment: @TrevanHetzel change its datatype from `date` to `datetime` OR `timestamp`. because `date` datatype contains only date data not the time data.

Comment: Gottcha. Okay, so if I do this and reinstall the WP plugin, am I going to have to input all the dates again?

Comment: Don't do this all rework, just change the datatype from phpmyadmin and edit the date values with respective time value.

Comment: Okay, so I see in phpmyadmin that there is also a time column, which lists times in a 12 hour format (like 3:00 PM). Instead of changing the the datatype of the ```date``` column to ```datetime```, could I somehow query that ```time``` column alongside the ```date``` column that already has data in it?